# Problems with Flutter: Problem building my application

Tags: android, flutter, android-profiler

I am doing a speed test comparison of Flutter and Apache Cordova, I've created a very simple app using Flutter and heard about Android Profiler. Since I want to compare them I'd like to use the Android Profiler both with Flutter and Cordova, and not any other alternative. I have a problem though when I run the Android Profiler:

> Launching lib\main.dart on SM G991B in profile mode...
> Running Gradle task 'assembleProfile'...
> Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512m
> √ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-profile.apk (11.2MB).
> Error running com.example.weatherapp2. Default activity not found
> Unable to read manifest info from C:\Users\asd\Documents\weatherapp2\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk.
> Exception: Problem building Android application: see above error(s).

What I have tested since I've found this problem on other posts but not succeeded:

- Invalidate Caches / Restart
- Removed all apks inside the build folder
- Used flutter clean in the command line

Is there any solution for this?

I kept on testing some stuff and now I get this error:

> Error running com.example.weatherapp2. Default activity not found
> Unable to read manifest info from C:\Users\ara98\Documents\weatherapp2\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk.
> No application found for TargetPlatform.android_arm64.
> Is your project missing an android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml?
> Consider running "flutter create ." to create one.

Comment: Did you make any changes to your manifest file? Can you share it?

Comment: @tomerpacific I haven't touched the manifest files. But I do see an error there now: Attribute android:usesCleartextTraffic is not allowed here

Comment: If the APK without profiling runs as normal, you should consider reporting a bug to Android Studio's issue tracker, attaching the versions of Android Studio and Gradle, and the APK's and device's API level.